# How to add a code to wait for response?

Tags: java, android, servlets, android-asynctask

I would like to know how to wait for a response from the servlet before going to onPostExecute() method.

Please provide a solution.

EDIT: Edit version

```
Response responsed = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ArrayList<Farm> farmSend= dbFarm.getAllFarms();

        String result = "";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody postRequestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("farms", new Gson().toJson(farmSend))
                .add("dataToBeRetrieved", "getData")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(new ipconfig().getIp() + "MobileFarm")
                .post(postRequestBody)
                .build();

            try {
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        responsed = response;
                        Headers responHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0, size = responHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            Log.i("response: ", responHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responHeaders.value(i));
                        }
                        Log.i("response body: ", response.body().toString());
                    }
                });
                result = responsed.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT: This is my servlet code.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int addCount = 0;
        int updateCount = 0;

        System.out.println("farmer input form mobile upload");
        ArrayList<Farmer> farmers = new Gson().fromJson(request.getParameter("farmers"), new TypeToken<List<Farmer>>() {
        }.getType());
        for (int a = 0; a < farmers.size(); a++) {
            if (a < new FarmerDAO().getListOfFarmers().size()) {
                if (new FarmerDAO().updateFarmer(farmers.get(a))) {
                    updateCount++;
                }
            } else if (new FarmerDAO().registerFarmer(farmers.get(a))) {
                addCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(farmers.get(a).getFarmerID() + " not added/updated");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("farmer input count updated: " + updateCount);
        System.out.println("farmer input count added: " + addCount);

        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson("farmer input completed"));
    }
```

The only things being printed immediately are "farmer input from mobile upload" and "start loop". The subsequent print lines are not being printed before receiving any response.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You are sending a request and get a response. What else do you want to wait for?

Comment: @MuratK. I should be waiting for the servlet to response. But I'm receiving null, since the servlet hasn't finish running its tasks.

Comment: Okay i think I understood that you meant. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use these call backs provided by okhttp:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Asynchronous Get](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java) from the library itself which is basically a `Callback` as soon as a response is available.

From their docs

> Download a file on a worker thread, and get called back when the response is readable. The callback is made after the response headers are ready. Reading the response body may still block. OkHttp doesn't currently offer asynchronous APIs to receive a response body in parts.

```
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
          System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
        }

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
      }
    });
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: 03-22 20:47:54.964 20925-21675/com.example.josiah.bigassv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                             Process: com.example.josiah.bigassv2, PID: 20925
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'okhttp3.ResponseBody okhttp3.Response.body()' on a null object reference

Comment: @RubySenpaii What did you do? Edit your opening post with your changes.